# Page element that accepts dragged item from favourites bar

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop, copy-paste

What characteristics must a page element have for it to be able to accept an item that has been dragged from the favourites bar?

Comment: Changed your tags a bit. Might help anyone with a better answer than mine find this question a bit easier.

Comment: jldupont: Let's say I have an edit box in a page and that I want to make that edit box a drop target for any of the items in the favourites bar. How must I adjust the characteristics of the edit box so that it will accept the item from the favourites bar? Or, making use of Cogwheel's information, so that it will accept the copy of the item created by the browser?

Thanks for asking?

Comment: That's actually what I was trying to get at. The edit box is already set up as the target for drag drops. The problem is in the way IE handles the drag off the favorites bar. As soon as you drag the favorite over the document (no matter what part of the document you drag it over), IE wants to use it as a "go to this address" command. And this is entirely separate from the fact that what it copies isn't just the url. Try dragging one of your favorites into a notepad window...

Comment: Yup, I got that. What I was hoping was that, having made just an edit box in a page displayed in IE an acceptable target (rather than the whole page) I could use jQuery or Javascript code to discern whether what had been transferred was just a URL or what looks like an .ini when you copy it into an editor (as you suggested). 

In short, unfortunately, the text element in an editor is able to interpret the contents of clipboard as an if they were an .ini but the text element in a edit box (in IE) cannot. Still wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any standard way to do this that would work in more than a single browser. HTML/JavaScript don't have any provisions for receiving drag drops from outside the document.

I believe this is something that Google is working to get included in HTML 5 to help with Wave.

Comment: If I told you that you can drag-and-drop a favourite from the bar to the edit box for the 'add subscription' form in the Google Reader, in FF and Chrome but not IE8 would that make a difference to your answer?

Comment: Basically what's going on is that they're treating the drag off the favorites bar as a copy and then pasting the result into the edit box. You should be able to see the same behavior if you drag text from another program (notepad, word, etc) into an edit box in IE.

Comment: To make something like this work in IE would probably require an IE addon. All of the copying and pasting is going on behind the scenes in the OS/browser, entirely outside the reach of any web standards currently in use.

Comment: Cogwheel, you are (of course) correct. I've just tried it. I'm going to have to approach this problem differently, I'm afraid.